# Object constructor points to the original constructor not prototype.constructor after redefining prototype of constructor function

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor, prototype

For example:

```
function F() {};
F.prototype = {
    test: function() { console.log('test'); }
};

console.log(F.prototype.constructor); // [Function: Object]

F.prototype = 'string';

var o = new F();
console.log(F.prototype.constructor); // [Function: String]
console.log(F.prototype);             // string
console.log(o.constructor);           // [Function: Object]

o.test();  // Can't work
```

In the code above, the initial constructor is `F()`, the `F.prototype.constructor`. But then I reset the `F.prototype` to `'string'`. And there are my questions:

1. After reset `F.prototype` to `'string'`, why `F.prototype.constructor` becomes `[Function: String]`. In other words, which determine the value of
   `F.prototype.constructor`?
2. I have known that the new object will inherit the properties of `prototype` object, so is `constructor` property. But why the constructor of object `p` was the original constructor `[Function: Object]`, not `[Function: String]`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: ok, @Liam. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor field is nothing special, it's like any other field.

**Answer for #1**:

```
F.prototype = "string";
console.log(F.prototype.constructor); // function String
```

logs `function String` because it's the same as

```
console.log("string".constructor); // function String
```

**Answer for #2**:

Every objects internal `__proto__` field must be `typeof x === "object"`. At the end of the prototype chain there always is a `null` value (usually it's the `Object.prototype.__proto__` one), and there are no cycles allowed. You assigned a primitive `string` to the constructors `prototype` field (`typeof F.prototype === "string"`), which cannot be used as `__proto__`, so the `new` operator just falls back to construct the object with a default prototype, which is `Object.prototype`.

Comment: Good answer! Thanks!

Comment: And I want to know is there any way to print the source code of the constructor, not just its type `[Function: Object]`?

Comment: @zhenguoli `constructor.toString()`

Comment: @Bergi, ok, i know.